# In Emacs how do I make a local variable safe to be set in a file for all possible values

Tags: variables, emacs, elisp

In Elisp I have introduced for a special custom mode a variable like:

```
(defvar leo-special-var "")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'leo-special-var)
```

Now I set this variable in files I with the lines (*in the file to edit*):

```
# Local Variables:
# leo-special-var: "-d http://www.google.com.au"
# End:
```

And I want to consider this variable as "safe *for all its values*. That's why `safe-local-variable-values` doesn't help. Instead I tried (*in the lisp code*):

```
# setting the symbol property of the variable
(put 'leo-special-var 'safe-local-variable 'booleanp)
```

but without success. Do I do something wrong when setting the symbol property? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you really want to state that it is safe for ***all*** values then use this:

```
(put 'leo-special-var 'safe-local-variable (lambda (_) t))
```

The function to test safety here returns non-`nil` for any value.

(But I'd think that you probably do **not** want to state that a variable is safe for any value.)

Comment: This is not what I *wanted* (I wanted a solution making it only safe for strings), but it is what I *asked* for. Good on you, @Drew!

Comment: I'd recommend against using this because it's erring on the unsafe side.

Comment: @stefan: I recommended against it also. But the question was how to do it.

Answer (score 27):

You want to use

```
(put 'leo-special-var 'safe-local-variable #'stringp)
```

to say that it is safe as long as it's a string.

Answer (score 5):

It's in the manual: `(elisp) File Local Variables`

```
   You can specify safe values for a variable with a
`safe-local-variable' property.  The property has to be a function of
one argument; any value is safe if the function returns non-`nil' given
that value.  Many commonly-encountered file variables have
`safe-local-variable' properties; these include `fill-column',
`fill-prefix', and `indent-tabs-mode'.  For boolean-valued variables
that are safe, use `booleanp' as the property value.  Lambda
expressions should be quoted so that `describe-variable' can display
the predicate.

   When defining a user option using `defcustom', you can set its
`safe-local-variable' property by adding the arguments `:safe FUNCTION'
to `defcustom' (*note Variable Definitions::).
```

Comment: I know of this documentation, but I don't understand it fully: Should I replace `'boleanp` withn `stringp`, because `leo-special-var`myvariable is a string variable?

Comment: Yes, `stringp` would be what you need. If you check the help for `booleanp` you'll see that it returns `t` *only* for the values `t` and `nil`, so it would have returned `nil` for all the values you used, thus indicating that they were not safe.